# can't get eventhandler to work

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I work on binding a button with a function that submit input into backend 
I have the html file where I declare the file.js where the logic implemented my code is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 console.log("1");
$(function() {
    FastClick.load(document.body);

 console.log("1");
});


$('.containerHeader').on('click',function(){
    $that = $(this);
    $that.parent().toggleClass('active');
     console.log("2");
});


$('#contact-form').bind('submit',function( event, submit ){
    var quizAnswer= {};
    event.preventDefault();
    quizAnswer.aa= $('#big-data-form').find('input:radio[name="cc-radio-group"]:checked').val();
    quizAnswer.bb= $('#social-form').find('input:radio[name="ss-radio-group"]:checked').val();
    quizAnswer.cc= $('#cloud-form').find('input:radio[name="ww-radio-group"]:checked').val();
    quizAnswer.dd= $('#mobile-form').find('input:radio[name="tt-radio-group"]:checked').val();
     console.log("3");
    var contactForm = $("#contact-form");
    var contactInfo = {};
    contactInfo.firstName = contactForm.find('input[name="first-name-input"]').val();
    contactInfo.lastName = contactForm.find('input[name="last-name-input"]').val();
    contactInfo.phone = contactForm.find('input[name="phone-input"]').val();
    contactInfo.email = contactForm.find('input[name="email-input"]').val();
    contactInfo.company = contactForm.find('input[name="company-input"]').val();
     console.log("4");

    submitToBackend(contactInfo,quizAnswer);
     console.log("5");

});
```

Comment: What about your html?? Can you show of that?

Comment: _"the problem there is nothing printed out to the screen"_ - Do you mean nothing is printed to the browser's console? Have you (a) included jquery.js; and (b) included the above code after the form element and/or in a document ready handler?

Comment: put this `event.preventDefault();` at the top of the function

Comment: What `console` is printed? Did it reach to the end? Did your objects `quizAnswer` and `contactInfo` where filled? Did `submitToBackend` is called? So many things to check before ask!

Comment: @JayHarris - OP already has that towards the bottom.

Comment: @nnnnnn so it doesn't matter where it's placed, it'll still work initially ?

Comment: @JayHarris - As long as it's called before the function returns it doesn't matter, so if it's placed later in the function you need to be confident that no errors will occur before that line. (Because if an uncaught error occurs before that line then the function would abort without reaching it so then the form would still submit. So yes, it probably is best to place it at the top, but it's not _required._)

Comment: @nnnnnn...I meant to the console, as you may noticed I put some console.log, and I put similar into the function.

Comment: Nada - OK, so it could be one of the things I mentioned after that.  Have you (a) included jquery.js before the above code, and (b) included the above code after the form element and/or in a document ready handler?

Comment: I included     jquery.js and I included the code in document ready handler    $(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("1");
 //Init FastClick plugin
 $(function() {
     FastClick.load(document.body);
     console.log("1");
 });

Comment: Anyone can help me out of this one?

Comment: Can you please click "edit" to add the details of the document ready handler to your question? The code you added to the comment is confusing because with no line breaks we can't tell how much is commented out by the `//` part, and also you haven't shown where the code from your question fits in the ready handler.

Comment: @nnnnn I just added it into the question, please look there

Comment: Could you make a JSFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: The document ready code you just added to the question wouldn't work because it is missing a closing `});`, and also your ready handler doesn't call the `.on("submit"...` code that you originally asked about.

Comment: @nnnnnn I just edited the original question once again and added the whole code block. because as I mentioned at the beginning, I'm very new to javascript and not sure what you mean by that ready handler does not call .on("submit"...

Comment: OK, that's better, now we can see it all in context. The code as it is currently shown in your question is missing a closing `});` right at the end, and that would stop the whole thing from working such that nothing would be logged to the console at all. Is that just a copy/paste error?

Comment: @nnnnnn no, it is not I just tried that and it did not change anything, I simply running out of  my mind what could be the problem?